# How to map property and value of an object to a table?

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, dictionary

This is my code so far, pulling historical currency data based on a 'base' rate and selected date. Is there a way to display the data returned  in columns 'currency name' and 'rate'? My code so far is below and here: http://codepen.io/co851002/pen/PWqVwr

```
var date = '2017-01-06'
var base = 'USD'
var API_request = 'https://api.fixer.io/' + date + '?base=' + base;

var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      rates: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios.get(API_request)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.data.rates)
        th.setState({
          rates: result.data.rates
        });
      })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;

    return (
      <div className="table">
    <table >
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Currency</th>
             <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
                    <tr>
              <td>Currency goes here</td>  
              <td>Value goes here</td>  
                    </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.keys(rates)` to `.map` over your data and return the desired DOM elements on each iteration.

> [**Object.keys()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
>
> *The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties...*

In other words `Object.keys` will give you an array with all the different currency types looking something like this:

```
["AUD", "BGN", "BRL", ...]
```

Now you can use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over the array and return what ever needs to be returned.

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> *The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.*

```
{Object.keys(rates).map(function(value, idx) {
  return <tr key={idx}>
    <td>{value}</td>
    <td>{rates[value]}</td>
  </tr>
})}
```

Here is an example.

```js
var date = '2017-01-06'
var base = 'USD'
var API_request = 'https://api.fixer.io/' + date + '?base=' + base;

var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      rates: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios.get(API_request)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.data.rates)
        th.setState({
          rates: result.data.rates
        });
      })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    var rates = this.state.rates;
    return (
      <div className="table">
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Currency</th>
             <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         {Object.keys(rates).map(function(value, idx) {
           return <tr key={idx}>
             <td>{value}</td>
             <td>{rates[value]}</td>
           </tr>
         })}
       </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.8.1/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidDomain - I can get some sleep now :)